# Job title spelling

Tags: orthography, professions

I have a question regarding my job position and its spelling - I develop mobile apps, what would be the correct spelling of my job position to put on my LinkedIn page:

- Mobile Application Developer
- Mobile Applications Developer
- Mobile App Developer
- Mobile Apps Developer

Or something completely different?

Comment: They all communicate to me.

Comment: And are there any differences?

Comment: In my mind the first two are more conservative or formal, while the last two are more modern and informal. There is a technical distinction between the singular an plural forms but neither one inhibits communication

Comment: Just a bit concerned about the abbreviated form, *M.A.D.*

Comment: While either singular or plural is understandable, I think the singular form is much more common in job titles.  See, for example, an "Account Manager" in sales, or a "Truck Driver".  This is not always true, as it is more common to see "Tools Developer" over "Tool Developer" in software, but that is a rare exception. In most cases, the noun object of a job title's verb is left singular (e.g. "Connector Developer", "User Interface Developer", "Chat System Developer")

Comment: Thank you @MarkThompson for explanation along with examples! I think I'll follow your advice.

Comment: I'd go for something completely different:Developer of Mobile Applications, then as a bonus you have the far more respectable DMA or DoMA.

Comment: The right place to ask could be a relevant tech Q&A on SE or rightaway on SO

Comment: "Mobile Application Developer" is the done thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these are correct and clear, but the most typical description for professionals in your field is "Mobile Application Developer."